# C# - OCR multicolor text using Tesseract 4

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract for doing OCR on a book. There are several pages having titles that have gradient text and have multiple background colors i.e.

[image]

(Just a mock up)

How can I do OCR on this type of image using tesseract 4.

**What I have tried:**
Grayscaled image and then tried but no success.

Comment: detect the situation, **fix** it using low level image processing routines (here: invert the top/bottom half, also take care of colors, don't just convert to grayscale!), *then* feed a *usable* picture to tesseract

Comment: Grayscale the image, flood fill (for example) the upper left and bottom right corner with white, and feed that image to Tesseract. Works for me in Python and Tesseract 5.

Comment: I am very new to tesseract and OpenCV, can you please give more explanation or link to some docs.

Comment: please present some representative pictures of the situation. I understand your given picture here is a mock-up.